# Graph rendering framework for iOS that produce an aesthetically pleasing 2D layout?

Tags: ios, data-visualization, graphs

I am looking for a framework that plot a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) with nodes and edges in an aesthetically pleasing way. I would like to use it in my App creatating for Apple App Store.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile Graphviz libraries for iOS:

- free
- open source

Compilation instructions (I haven't tried myself):

- http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-devel/2011/001439.html
- http://www.graphviz.org/content/cant-cross-compile-graphviz
- [Build static Graphviz libraries for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7224827/395857)